# Nuxt & Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, sass, babeljs, nuxt.js

I have a basic Nuxt application that works just fine in Chrome and others recent browser but does not in the infamous Internet Explorer, even IE 11.

I have found that some JavaScript is not working althouth the code transpiled.

But most important my SCSS is not "transpiled" I mean by that, I was expecting kind of a css prefixing or something for compatibility.

For instance this :

```
&__stats {
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);

    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

Is transformed to this (in the  browser console) :

```
&__stats {
display: grid;

grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);

grid-gap: 10px;
margin-bottom: 64px;
margin-bottom: 4rem;
padding: 32px;
padding: 2rem;
}
```

I tried a lot of thing in my nuxt config file... Nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Basic:
Install autoprefixer and postcss in your project to add all required prefix.

Source:
From there is source: https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c3

Solution as I understand:
Add to proper place in **nuxt.config.js** and update nuxt to be greater than v0.6.7:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    postcss: [
      require('postcss-nested')(),
      require('postcss-responsive-type')(),
      require('postcss-hexrgba')(),
    ]
  }
```

Is there error when you try, to add something, in your webpack/nuxt configuration file?